# How do I enable DAC on a clustered SQL Server 2008 after I can no longer connect to SQL Server in any other way

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, dac

I'm having issues with SQLServer 2008 where a Server level triggered was not dropped correctly.

Articles on the web recommend dropping them through the DAC.

However, the DAC is disabled by default on Clustered environments.

How do I enable the DAC bearing in mind that I can no longer connect to the SQLServer 2008 instance in any other way.

cheers

andy

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/logon-triggers/) the only other alternative to drop these triggers is to stop your server and restart it using the [minimal configuration mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186400.aspx). You can obviously then enable the DAC.